# Наследование конструктора базового класса

Tags: c#, наследование

Есть базовый класс и наследник. У обоих одинаковые параметры конструктора.

Мне подсказали, что, если параметры одинаковые, то конструктор в наследнике можно не писать *или что-то типа того*.

Однако, роясь я гугле, я не нашел пример наследования с одинаковыми параметрами, и во всех примерах параметры у базового класса и наследника были разными.

Короче говоря, как должен быть написан этот код правильно?

```
class CustomCommand {
    public CustomCommand(string t, string a) {
        trigger = new Regex(t);
        triggerStr = t;
        ansver = a; 
    }
    public virtual void Fire(string n, string m, string c) { }

    public Regex trigger;
    public string triggerStr;
    public string ansver;
};

class EasyCommand : CustomCommand {
    public EasyCommand(string t, string a) : base(t, a) { }

    public override void Fire(string n, string m, string c) {
        m = "123";
    }
};
```

Comment: Всё правильно, по другому и не написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкторы не передаются производному классу при наследовании. И если в базовом классе не определен конструктор по умолчанию без параметров, а только конструкторы с параметрами то в производном классе мы обязательно должны вызвать один из этих конструкторов через ключевое слово `base`.

```
public   class Person
{
public string FirstName { get;  set; }
public string LastName {get; set; }

public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
}

public void Display()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{FirstName} {LastName}");
}
}
public  class Employee : Person
{
public string Company { get; set; }
public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string comp)
    : base(firstName, lastName)
{
    Company = comp;
}
}
```

Если из класса `Employee` уберем определение конструктора:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
  public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

В данном случае мы получим ошибку, так как класс `Employee` не соответствует классу `Person`, а именно не вызывает конструктор базового класса. Даже если бы мы добавили какой-нибудь конструктор, который бы устанавливал все те же свойства, то мы все равно бы получили ошибку:

```
public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string comp)
{
  FirstName = firstName;
  LastName = lastName;
  Company = comp;
}
```

*То есть в классе `Employee` через ключевое слово `base` надо явным образом вызвать конструктор класса `Person`:*
Либо в качестве альтернативы мы могли бы определить в базовом классе конструктор без параметров:

```
public Person()
{
    FirstName = "Tom";
    LastName = "Johns";
    Console.WriteLine("Вызов конструктора без параметров");
}
```

Вот полная статья о [Наследовании](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.7.php)

Answer (score 0):

Да, вам придется реализовывать конструкторы в классе-наследнике, а в них использовать ключевое слово `base`, чтобы вызвать конструктор базового класса, потому что конструкторы не наследуются. Мы их должны явно прописывать в классе наследнике, тем самым указывая, каким образом базовый класс должен быть инициализирован.